# Svelte data prop returning "undefined"

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am using SvelteKit to create a small site. I am trying to implement a skeleton or placeholder card while the data loads. I keep encountering "undefined" when trying to check. Please see my code and let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

In my `+page.server.js` :

```js
import { projectData } from '$lib/data.js';

export async function load() {
    try {
        const projects = projectData[0].content;

        //console.log('Fetched projects:', projects);

        return {
            summaries: projects.map((project) => ({
                title: project.title,
                image: project.image,
                url: project.url
            }))
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        return {
            status: 500,
            error: new Error('Internal Server Error')
        };
    }
}
```

In my `+page.svelte` file:

```html
<script>
  export let data;

  $: isDataLoaded = data && data.summaries && Array.isArray(data.summaries);

  // keeps printing "undefined"
  console.log(isDataLoaded);
</script>

{#if isDataLoaded}
  <p>Content goes here...</p>
{:else}
  <p>Loading...</p>
{/if}
```

Never displays "Loading..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data from a `load` is directly passed to the page component when it is created.
I.e. there is no loading state here.

An exception would be if you [stream promises](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#streaming-with-promises) which is not the case here.

The `console.log` will always give you `undefined` because reactive statements run *after* any non-reactive code ([example](https://svelte.dev/repl/2ee75d454a404b42b849489d6d3aeaed?version=4.2.8)). Change it to `$: console.log(...)` and it should log a value.